# Applet can be loaded in IE and Firefox,but failed in Safari5.1

Tags: java, japplet

I use Safari5.1 to load an signed applet on Windows desktop, but it failed and seems the JAVA plug-in NOT started.
The html code like below, do i need to add other parameter for Safari 5.1 ?  And is there any other method to load applet in Safari? thanks.
system is Windows, browser version is Safari 5.1

```
<!--[if !IE]> Firefox and others will use outer object -->

<object classid="java:com.keithley.SCPI.SCPIApplet.class" type="application/x-java-applet;version=1.6" archive="../jar/SCPI.jar" height="480" width="640">
<param name = "scriptable"   value = "true">
<!-- Konqueror browser needs the following param -->
<param name = "ARCHIVE"    value = "../jar/SCPI.jar">
     <!-- (Microsoft Internet Explorer) will use inner object -->
     <object classid="clsid:8AD9C840-044E-11D1-B3E9-00805F499D93" codebase="http://java.sun.com/update/1.6.0/jinstall-6u35-windows-i586.cab#Version=6,0,0,10"
             height="480" width="640" >
             <param name = "CODE"       value = "com.keithley.SCPI.SCPIApplet.class">
             <param name = "ARCHIVE"    value = "../jar/SCPI.jar">
             <param name = "type"       value = "application/x-java-applet;version=1.6">
             <param name = "scriptable" value = "false">
      </object>
       <!--[if !IE]> close outer object -->
</object>
```

Comment: Did you check the web inspector on Safari 5.1 to see what kind of errors the applet is giving you?

Comment: Thanks Schuster, i can't find the web inspector, my Safari is 5.1.7 on Windows7-32bit.Does it only exist in iOS and OS X?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with `<object>` and `<embed>` instead of `<object>` inside another `<object>`:

```
<object classid = "clsid:8AD9C840-044E-11D1-B3E9-00805F499D93"  
        codebase="http://java.sun.com/update/1.6.0/jinstall-6u35-windows-i586.cab#Version=6,0,0,10" 
        width="640" height="480" id="yourAppletId">
    <param name = "code" value = "com.keithley.SCPI.SCPIApplet.class">
    <param name = "archive" value = "../jar/SCPI.jar">
    <param name = "mayscript" value = "true">
    <param name = "scriptable" value = "true">
    <param name = "type" value = "application/x-java-applet;version=1.6">
    <comment>
        <embed type = "application/x-java-applet;version=1.6"
               code = "com.keithley.SCPI.SCPIApplet.class" 
               archive = "../jar/SCPI.jar"
               scriptable = "true"
               width = "640" height = "480"
               name = "yourAppletId"
               mayscript = "true"
               scriptable = "true">
        </embed>
    </comment>
</object>
```

Besides if you want to check if the java plugin start, you can go to **control panel > Java**, select the **Advanced** tab an on **Java console** option select **Show console** radio button.

Hope this helps,

Comment: it still prompt "Missing plug-in". As you suggest, i select the "Show console" and then it should pop up the JAVA console when i load the applet, but no. Do you have other suggestions?

Comment: BTW, it seems that the tag "<embed>" does not meet the W3C specfication, so i just can use "<object>" nested structure.

Answer (score 0):

Done, Actually Safari 5.1.7 in Windows does not recognize the JAVA, when we open the page containing JAVA applet,it will pop up the alert "Missing plug-in".